# z-index not working when parent has pos: absolute and his parent has pos: relative

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have provided a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dCYdw/

Its a horrible example, but the problem can been seen.

`.levelFive` is the problem. This should be in front of all other elements as it has a `z-index` of 3 and the others have 2 and 1 going upwards.

`.levelFive` is only line 146 of the css in case you can't find it.

Comment: How do you want it to look? Did you try changing the `position`ing of `.levelFive` to `relative`? Why do you need to use `absolute`?

Comment: i want .levelFive to be in front of all elements. Of i didn't change levelFive to relative, i need it to be absolute ;)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put `position: relative;` and `float: left;` on `.internalMenu > ul > li, .levelThree > ul > li` and also wrap `ul.levelFive` into a `div` like you did with `ul.levelFour`

See http://jsfiddle.net/dCYdw/12/